# ngFor loop continue executing and crash the app in ionic 3 with firebase database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, for-loop, ionic3

I'm developing `Hybrid` chatting app using `ionic 3 framework` with `Firebase` backend. I'm filtering some types of data which i get from firebase. it's working but for loop is continuously executing and after some time my app crash.
I exactly want to check mobile number of user(Which i get from database) and my contact list(User's phone-book). Here i have also added some JavaScript functions for remove space between number and get last 10 digits of number. Please suggest me if you know any better way to do it.
Please find my code below. Thank you.

> Html

```
<div *ngFor="let key of filteredusers; let i = index">
  <ion-item *ngIf="arraysEqual2(key)">
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="{{key.photoURL}}">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{key.displayName}}</h2>
    <p *ngIf="key.phoneNumbers">{{key.mobile}}</p>
    <button ion-button outline item-end (click)="sendreq(key,i)">Add</button>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

> Ts

```
  arraysEqual2(data) {
    var number
    if (data.mobile) {
      number = data.mobile
    } else {
      number = ''
    }
    var contact: any
    for (contact of this.contactlist) {
      if (contact.phoneNumbers && this.setnumber(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value) == number) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }

  setnumber(str) {
    var filter1 = str.replace(/\s/g, '')
    var final = filter1.substr(str.length - 10)
    console.log(final)
    return final
  }
```

Comment: what's the value in filteredusers?

Comment: Hi Mridul, thanks for comment please check below image.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o4EUTB7HvBcvCdQt-4MQt8lHN-E1q9FJ

Comment: 1. What are the contents of `this.contactlist`? 2. Also, what exactly are you trying to do in `setnumber(...)` and in the `for-loop`?

Comment: 1.the contents of this.contactlist is displaying in this image " https://drive.google.com/open?id=14Y7TZQjnBsx5llCp8s9A5ATKBTWBBM2x "

2. I'm trying to remove space between numbers and remove +91 so i can match exact mobile number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let key of filteredusers; let i = index">
<h2 *ngIf="arraysEqual2(key)">
  <!-- image -->
  <h2>displayName {{i}}</h2>
  <p >key.mobile {{i}}</p>
  <!-- <button ion-button outline item-end (click)="sendreq(key,i)">Add</button> -->
</h2>
```

TYPESCRITP

```js
filteredusers:any = [{mobile:'9876543212'}, {mobile:'9876543211'}]
contactlist:any = [{phoneNumbers:'+91 9876 543 210'}, {phoneNumbers:'+91 9876 543 211'}, {phoneNumbers:'+91 9876 543 212'}, {phoneNumbers:'+91 9876 543 213'}]

// get last 10 digit mobile no at once [this will reduce your code execution, currently in your code setnumber function excute filteredusers.length * contactlist.length approximatily ]
filterMoileNo(){
  this.contactlist.forEach(element => {
  element.phoneNumbers = this.setnumber(element.phoneNumbers)
  // for your array
    element.phoneNumbers[0].value = this.setnumber(element.phoneNumbers[0].value)
  });
}

arraysEqual2(data) {
  var number
  if (data.mobile) {
    number = data.mobile
  } else {
    number = ''
  }

  return this.contactlist.some(el => el.phoneNumbers == number);
}

setnumber(str) {
  var filter1 = str.replace(/\s/g, '')
  var final = filter1.substr(filter1.length - 10)
  return final
}
```

call filterMoileNo() function whenever contactlist updated/load (filter contact no. format at once)

Note : Do not use console in nested looping because it take more memory to write, avoid nested looping if your logic can be done in simple way.

please try this, i hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks Praveen Patel it's working but this is not exactly issue. The loop is continuously execute and i'm getting "console.log(final)" console continuously. The for-loop should execute only one time. I know i'm doing something wrong but i can't find it yet.

Comment: please put console below this statement
if (contact.phoneNumbers && this.setnumber(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value) == number) {
        return true
      }
console.log(contact)

and check how many time it prints

Comment: i have checked its continuously prints until the app crash.